# What are the functions of these parts of the brain (MRI)?

Tags: brain, function, multiple-sclerosis, optic-nerve

This is an MRI images of my brain. There are three red arrows pointing at there parts of the brain. 
I would like to the functions of these three parts, Please?

Are they control motion, speaking, hearing, smelling, emotions or something else?

I'm diagnosed with MS. I had optic neuritis. I don't feel anything else wrong. But they are three parts so I think there are three symptoms, not just one. So, would you help me discover what else I have?

I know that It is not allowed to diagnose people in this site. But this is not diagnoses. I just would like to know what the functions of these parts of the brain are.

Thank you very much,[image]
[image]

Comment: With an MRI image there is usually a paper written by a radiologist with a detailed description of any abnormality. Can you find any?

Comment: Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwgCajJ9oB7FRnJuOXJycEc3ODg

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your diagnosis. This is not answering the question, but it is worth noting that white spots on the MRI from MS frequently come and go, and frequently aren't associated with any symptom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three spots in the brain do not automatically mean three different symptoms. Even if those spots are abnormal, they do not necessary cause any damage.

A doctor in the "2. MRI report" says there are:

> ...few bilateral **parietal** subcortical tiny white matter
>   foci...warrant further evaluation to exclude possibility of early
>   onset MS.

So, there are 3 *tiny* spots in the white matter of the **parietal lobes** of the brain.

[Parietal Lobes (Brainmadesimple.com)](http://brainmadesimple.com/parietal-lobe.html):

> Function: Processes sensory information that had to do with **taste,
>   temperature, and touch**

[Brain Lesions (MedicineNet)](http://www.medicinenet.com/brain_lesions_lesions_on_the_brain/article.htm):

> Parietal lobes are where sensation is processed and interpreted. Aside
>   from touch, **pressure** and **pain,** there is also the concept of **spatial
>   cognition,** where the brain recognizes where the body is in
>   relationship to the area around it.

[What is the function of the parietal lobe? (Reference.com)](https://www.reference.com/science/function-parietal-lobe-6297ec84190d8cab):

> Patients with damage to the parietal lobe can suffer from **language or
>   memory loss** and might also be **unable to hold a gaze.** Thus, the
>   parietal lobe helps people recall words when speaking.
>
> The visual processing within the parietal lobe facilitates **writing** and
>   **mathematical calculations.** The parietal lobe is also responsible for
>   **perception** and **language processing.**

[Memory Dysfunction in Multiple Sclerosis...(American Journal of Neuroradiology)](http://www.ajnr.org/content/20/10/1956.full):

> Lesions of the deep white matter in the left parietal lobe have been
>   found to be associated with **impaired performance on the paired
>   associates test, a test of learning and memory.**

I'm not saying you should or will suffer from any of these symptoms. A neurologist, who can perform an exact neurological examination might detect some signs you are not aware of.